# ml5.js error when creating a neural network

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, ml5.js

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MqJzMvHE3E&t=480s on shape classification and I'm encountering the problem

```
Uncaught Error: Error in oneHot: depth must be >=2, but it is 1
    at oneHot_ (tf-core.esm.js:17:357944)
    at Object.oneHot (tf-core.esm.js:17:71801)
    at NeuralNetworkData.js:560:38
    at tf-core.esm.js:17:40461
    at t.scopedRun (tf-core.esm.js:17:40603)
    at t.tidy (tf-core.esm.js:17:40355)
    at Object.rn (tf-core.esm.js:17:67569)
    at t.value (NeuralNetworkData.js:550:15)
    at NeuralNetworkData.js:533:33
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I'm using ml5.js version 0.6.0 and here is my js file:

```
const circles = []

function preload() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let index = nf(i+1, 4, 0);
        circles[i] = loadImage(`/data/circle/circle${index}.png`)
    }
}

let shapeClassifier;

function setup() {
    let options = {
        inputs: [128, 128, 4],
        task: 'imageClassification',
        debug: true
      };
      shapeClassifier = ml5.neuralNetwork(options);
    
      for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        shapeClassifier.addData({ image: circles[i] }, { label: 'circle' });
      }
      shapeClassifier.normalizeData();
      shapeClassifier.train({ epochs: 50 }, () => finishedTraining());
}
    
function finishedTraining() {
    console.log('finished training!');
}
```

I'm not familiar with ml5 or machine learning in general so I have no idea what this error means or how to fix it, I would really appreciate the help!

I expected it to work and start training the neural network but it didn't and got this error instead

I expected it to start training the model on the input data but instead got that error

Comment: The problem is that all of your inputs have the same `label`.  You must have 2 or more labels in order to classify.  Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73365664/uncaught-in-promise-error-error-error-in-onehot-depth-must-be-2-but-it-i

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: Error in oneHot: depth must be >=2, but it is 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73365664/uncaught-in-promise-error-error-error-in-onehot-depth-must-be-2-but-it-i)